# Vuex: committing an object then finding it by ID

Tags: ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to commit something to my Vuex state using this method.

```
getVariableLookup: ({ commit, _state }, payload) => {
  http.get(`/frame_variables/${payload}`)
    .then(response => {
      commit('addVariableLookup', response.data.frame_variable.body)
    })
}
```

This works fine, but I want to store the `payload` alongside the response. I cannot seem to commit it as an object like so.

```
commit('addVariableLookup', { id: payload, body: response.data.frame_variable.body })
```

That method returns this:

[image: weird log]

**Update**

Turns out it was setting the data fine, I just can't retrieve it with this code:

```
const body = this.variableLookups.find(x => x.id === v.v_id)
```

`this.variableLookups` returns them all. How can I find the individual object?

Comment: How are you defining the `addVariableLookup` mutation? Also, if you're using vue-devtools, can you see the mutation fire?

Comment: There's not necessarily anything wrong here. The **Getter & Setter** stuff just means that those properties have JS getters and setters defined, which is to be expected as Vue adds them as part of the reactivity system. If you expand those objects you should find the correct values lurking within.

Comment: My bad, will update the question. vue-devtools is telling me I've got the right data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grabbing the body for the relevant id should be just:

```js
const entry = this.variableLookups.find(x => x.id === v.v_id)
const body = entry ? entry.body : null
```

Whether the ternary/`null` are required would depend on whether you already have logic to prevent that case occurring. You will need to be careful to wait until after the action has loaded the data before you try to grab it.

What you're doing might be better achieved using an object to map the ids to the bodies, rather than using an array. The usual caveat around adding properties to objects applies.

Comment: > ... wait until after the action has loaded the data...
When will I learn? Thank-you.